# How to set 2 different 404 pages based on URL value?

Tags: .htaccess

Right now I got the following in my .htaccess file:

```
#Redirect 404 errors to homepage (English)
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

But recently I have added some French content on my site. The url format of that is like this: *domain.com/fr/[article]* and the the default English content is just on the root *domain.com/[article]*.

Now I want to make the 404 ErrorDocument to be `ErrorDocument 404 /fr/` whenever there is /fr/ in the beginning of the url as shown above.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be easier if you use a default php file as error page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

And from your `error.php` you have something like:

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$parts = explode('/', $path_parts['dirname']);
if (in_array("fr", $parts))
{
    // show French error message
    // or if u want to redirect to the root of that language
    //header("Location: http://domain.com/fr/");
}
else
{
    // show English error message
    // or if u want to redirect to the root of that language
    //header("Location: http://domain.com/");
}
```